# how to compare 2d array values in if statement

Tags: android

how to compare 2 dimension array value in if statement. my array values are numeric like  this 12,3,23,,31 etc i want to compare each two values in edittext

below is my code which get 2d array in edittext

```
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];

    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);

    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);

    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);

    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);

    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);

    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);

    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);
```

how to compare value which is greater

```
     if((a[0][0]>(a[0][0])
     {
         mMonth=mMonth-1;
     }
```

Comment: it is wrong format  to compare  if((a[0][0]>(a[0][0])

Comment: The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

Comment: (a[0][0] and (a[0][1] both are integer values how to compare them both??

Comment: how they are integer if they are retrieved from an EditText, also you have initialized them as String,  first parse them as an integer as `if(Integer.parserInt(a[0][0]>Integer.parserInt(a[0][0])`

Comment: accepted answer will not give desired result for a[0][0]=12,a[0]a[1]=5
check it out

Comment: check it out ..for more detail about CompareTo http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
if(s1.compareTo(s2)==0){
            // Both Are equals
        }else if(s1.compareTo(s2)<0){
            // s1 less then s2
        }else{
            // s1 greater then s2
        }
```

**IN your case**

```
if(a[0][0].compareTo(a[0][1])==0){
            // Both Are equals
        }else if(a[0][0].compareTo(a[0][1])<0){
            // a[0][0] less then a[0][1]
        }else{
            // a[0][0] greater then a[0][1]
        }
```

Comment: I beg a pardon but oblige to say that it 'll not give desire result for
a[0][0]=12,a[0][1]=5. checkout http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm

Answer (score 0):

your array is of string type so it **cannot be compared** using **>** symbol so convert string array to int array

**public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];**

change it to

**public static int[][] a = new int[6][7];**